# Flask SocketIO not connecting with client socket when using async_mode="threadind"

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, websocket, flask-socketio

I am using flask_socketio with threading and I want to emit event from thread.

```
sio = SocketIO(app, async_mode="threading")
```

when I add `async_mode="threding`, I can't able to connect client socket with flask socket.
It disconnect immadiately when I try to connect and not giving any error

[image]

Is there any way I can use socket with threading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions in the output of your server? The error is telling you that you don't have a websocket server installed, and suggest you install simple-websocket:

```
pip install simple-websocket
```

That should give you WebSocket support with the threading mode.

Alternatively, you can configure your client to connect using the polling transport instead of WebSocket.

Comment: When I install this package and try to connect socket with postman, the postman automatically close,
I even try with other socket testing tool and same issue, that it is not connecting

Comment: Did you look at the server logs? What is the connection being closed?